# Sharing of Sub Folders ownCloud

Tags: owncloud

I have a complicated system of folders and I need to share 2nd and 3rd level folders with certain groups of users while maintaining the full path to the folder.

Is this possible? I tried but without success as if I share a folder eg. Project 1->Administration with the "Group Administration" on the client I only see the Administration folder and I need, instead, to replicate the entire structure.

Thanks for the support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the current ownCloud sharing implementation this is simply not possible. Every shared item appears directly in the "Shared" folder of the user the file/folder is shared with.

Update: At the moment ownCloud (and I guess also nextCloud) allow a user to move around and rename files/folders shared with them. So even if you could enforce a certain structure on your users, they could always change it afterwards.

You could always report a feature request for it (or maybe there even already is one) here: https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/ .